# Vercel working deployment does not appear in "Deployments" list

Tags: reactjs, vercel

I'm having issues with Vercel.

Let's say the link [https://name-user.vercel.app/](https://name-user.vercel.app) points to the correct working deployment of the app.
However, in the "Deployments" page, I can see a list of deployments, each characterized by a different name, i.e. https://name-uawa5lkcv-user.vercel.app

However, none of these seems to work like the first one. There is actually a bug in each of these, as they look like some previous version of the app.

Also, there is no visible "Production deployment", as if this was hidden or deleted.

Where can I find the source code relative to the working deployment?
Was it somehow hidden?